# How do I cancel CFtpConnection::PutFile?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, ftp

ftp [server and client](http://CFtpConnection%3a%3aPutFile) (C windows) using a UDP socket.

The server puts files on the client using [CFtpConnection::PutFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67x0twby%28VS.80%29.aspx)

A large file takes several minutes, so the client needs to be able to cancel PutFile().

How do I check for a cancel udp message if PutFile() is busy transferring data? Create another thread....?

Any advice in the right direction is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need some level of control for the transfer process, you can't go with the high-level approach of `PutFile` and you 'll have to take a more direct role.

Open the remote file with [`CFtpConnection::OpenFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1st6z7sc.aspx) for writing, which will give you a `CInternetFile*`. You would then write data using [`CInternetFile::Write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6ff5x49.aspx) by yourself; this will also give you the option to stop sending data and close the connection at any time.

This page of WinInet documentation mentions a HOWTO and a sample in the MS Knowledge Base, which might be good to look into for an implementation.

Comment: thank you, appreciate the help, I will take a look into that.